# Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: java.io.EOFException in SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, split, transformation

I have a Spark program that converts cobol copybook data into XML when i try to run this i get errors like `java.io.EOFException` i googled it a lot but did not get much helpful links.

I have a sample file which is flat file(.bin file) and that i am able to convert comfortably into xml from copybook format. But i have another file which is flat file which is at this location

cobol Copybook file is kept at `file:///Users/admin/Desktop/Kafka/cobrix-master/cobrix-master/examples/example_data/edited1.cbl`

```
file:///Users/admin/Desktop/Kafka/cobrix-master/cobrix-master/examples/example_data/xyz_Input
```

When i run the program with my flat file i get errors

The error is like this

```
20:37:29.653 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.input.FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.nextKeyValue(FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(generated.java:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(generated.java:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1533)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1521)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1520)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1520)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1748)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1703)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1692)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2846)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2438)
    at za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.examples.CobolSparkExample1$.main(CobolSparkExample1.scala:54)
    at za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.examples.CobolSparkExample1.main(CobolSparkExample1.scala)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.input.FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.nextKeyValue(FixedLengthBinaryRecordReader.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(generated.java:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(generated.java:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


package za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.examples

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils.SparkUtils
import com.databricks.spark.xml._

object CobolSparkExample1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkBuilder = SparkSession.builder().appName("Cobol source reader example 1")
    val spark = sparkBuilder
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

       val df = spark
      .read
      .format("za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.source")

      .option("copybook", "file:///Users/admin/Desktop/Kafka/cobrix-master/cobrix-master/examples/example_data/edited1.cbl")
      .load("file:///Users/admin/Desktop/Kafka/cobrix-master/cobrix-master/examples/example_data/xyz_Input")


      df.printSchema()

    println(df.count)

       df.write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") 
      //.option(rowTag = "book", rootTag ="book")
      //.option("book", "book")
      .save("file:///Users/admin/Desktop/Kafka/cobrix-master/cobrix-master/examples/example_data/Output/newbooks.xml")


  }

}
```

Input source file is like this

```
ACHFOUND    079675882    1446320661365001Y00000   000M   8019721193     ACHFOUND       6613-144632                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             000875                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <EOR>
ACHFOUND    079675882    1446320661365001Y10000   S10    ACHFOUND    875079675882    144632                11180524180525SAFEWAY   21130     8019721193  ACHFOUND    1805241300000000000087500000000180524144632                BTALBERTSONS COMPANIES, LLC          9 0091372096500NATIONAL SERVICES CENTER           P.O. BOX 29093                     PHOENIX            AZ85038    STALBERTSONS LLC A SUB. OF ALBERTSONS COMPANIES, LLC          9 0091372096613                                                                                                                                 <EOR>
```

Comment: you should ask the 3rd party devs, that's not a standard format of Apache Spark

Comment: You mean to say we cannot use this type of flat file in Spark directly?  may be some other file converter can convert this file format into Apache Spark acceptable format?

Comment: I just wanted to say that the Cobol format is a 3rd party lib. I mean you should know this given that you have to add the lib to the classpath. The project is clearly this : https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix I'd start with asking the devs of the project as it might be an issue on their side

Comment: Hello as @UninformedUser said. If you ask on the github of Cobrix I guarantee there will be people that will try to help you. Before that, how sure are you in your data? There have been cases of people having `EOFException` dues to data problems.